# Value after Base64 encoding/decoding are not the same

Tags: android, encryption, base64

I need to encode/decode my data before storing in database but i have strange problem, After decoding, the value are not the same as first
for example look at this code why seedBytes1 and seedBytes2 are not the same? (I tried encodedSeedBytes.getBytes("US-ASCII") instead of encodedSeedBytes but no success)

```
seedBytes = new SecureRandom().generateSeed(16);
Log.i("LOG", "seedBytes1: " + seedBytes.toString()); // Before encoding
encodedSeedBytes = Base64.encodeToString(seedBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
decodedSeedBytes = Base64.decode(encodedSeedBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
Log.i("LOG", "seedBytes2: " + decodedSeedBytes.toString()); // After decoding
```

Result: (why this 2 value are not the same?)

```
I/LOG﹕ seedBytes1: [B@41764070
I/LOG﹕ seedBytes2: [B@41765bf0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a reference to the location of the object within the JVM memory and not the value of the seed itself.

[According to the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html) generateSeed() returns a Byte[].

You are calling toString() on an array of bytes which just returns it's location in memory.

To convert a byte[] into a string you can use

```
String s = new String(seedBytes);
```